# what is sql command for this group by?

Tags: sql, command

i have a table with this columns:"id,Nationalcode,Ccode,Ocode,Adate,..."
now i want do group by on Nationalcode, 
`select id,Kasset from allocate group by Kasset`

but for each Nationalcode there are several record hence hit to following error:
`Column 'allocate.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

what is correct command?

Comment: Please edit your question and show a) sample table data, and b) the output you want.  There are a number of ways to resolve your error, but without knowing what you want, it is hard to give an answer.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 1):

It's clear enough from the error message

> Column 'allocate.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an **aggregate function** or the **GROUP BY** clause

that while having *several* `Allocate.Id` values, e.g.

```
1, 2, 3
```

you have to figure out *one* with a help of *aggregate function*:

```
1, 2, 3 -> SUM()   -> 6
1, 2, 3 -> AVG()   -> 2
1, 2, 3 -> MIN()   -> 1
1, 2, 3 -> MAX()   -> 3
1, 2, 3 -> COUNT() -> 3
```

etc. The query should be

```
    select Max(Id), --TODO: Put the right function here 
           Kasset 
      from Allocate 
  group by Kasset
```

**Edit**: let's try finding out these *aggregate functions* (at least some of them), according to the example (see comments below)

```
id | Nationalcode | Ccode | Ocode | Kasset |    Adat
-------------------------------------------------------
 1 |          547 |  1910 |     1 |   4444 | 1995/09/27
 2 |          546 |  1910 |     1 |   2222 | 1995/12/14
 1 |          546 |  1910 |     1 |   4444 | 1995/01/01
```

The desired result is

```
 1 |          546 |  1910 |     1 |   4444 | 1995/09/27
 2 |          546 |  1910 |     1 |   2222 | 1995/12/14
```

the query can be

```
    select Max(Id),           -- ? Many options, Max among them 
           Min(Nationalcode), -- since 546, 547 -> 546 
           Max(Ccode),        -- ? Many options, Max among them
           Max(Ocode),        -- ? Many options, Max among them
           Kasset,            -- ? Many options, Max among them
           Max(Adat)          -- 1995/09/27, 1995/01/01 -> 1995/09/27 
      from Allocate 
  group by Kasset
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry Bychenko ,  if i want get end date for each group ,  in this case what is command?

Comment: @Hadi: Hi! You have to think on what *aggerate function* to use in the `select`.

Comment: yes if we want All field on `Select command` like `select Max(id),Nationalcode,Ccode,Ocode,Adate,... from Allocate   group by Kasset` ?

Comment: @Hadi: each field within `select` should be either in `group by` as well (e.g. `Kasset`) or wrapped in an *aggregate function* (e.g. `Max(id)` - `Max` is an aggregate function). In your case it can be something like `select Max(id),Max(Nationalcode),Max(Ccode),Max(Ocode),Max(Adate),... from Allocate group by Kasset`

Comment: No i want only aggregate function on one field like id.

Comment: @Hadi: Oh, but you *have to*: imagine, that you've got, say, *three* `Ccode` corresponding to *one* `Kasset` - `1`, `2`, `3`. *Which* value should be returned? It's an *aggregate function* that chooses from

Comment: for example we have this columns:`id,Nationalcode,Ccode,Ocode,Kasset,Adate` with these records:`1,546,1910,1,4444,1995/09/27` and `2,546,1910,1,2222,1995/12/14` and `1,547,1910,1,4444,1995/01/01`  i need to group by on Nationalcode and on each group last date record. therefore my result records are :`1,546,1910,1,4444,1995/09/27` and `2,546,1910,1,2222,1995/12/14`

Comment: @Hadi: according to your example, you can put `Max` on all the fields except `Kasset`. See my edit, please

Comment: result is: `1 546 1910 1 2222 1395/12/14` and `2 547 1910 1 4444 1395/09/27` if we use `max` for `Adate` it return `1395/09/27` for `547` while it isn't correct.

Comment: If having two `Nationalcode` values `546, 547` you want to return `546` you, probably, should take `Min`: `...Min(Nationalcode),...`

Answer (score 0):

> GROUP BY clause is always used with aggregate function (i.e. SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG functions)

Try this:

```
select count(id) [Count], Kasset from allocate group by Kasset
```